# Getting the URLs of the SharePoint sites, lists and list views using Managed Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model, url

Let's say that I have created:

- A SharePoint site collection at `http://mysharepoint/`.
- A subsite of that site collection titled `Team site` at `http://mysharepoint/teamsite/`.
- A list titled `My List` at `http://mysharepoint/teamsite/Lists/mylist/`.
- A list view titled `My View` at 'http://mysharepoint/teamsite/Lists/mylist/Forms/myview.aspx'

In the Managed Client Object model code, let's say that I managed to reference:

- The subsite as `Web teamsite;`
- The list as `List mylist;`
- The list view as `View myview;`

Is there a way to get the corresponding URLs from those three objects? Thanks.

Comment: i assume you already tried teamsite.Url etc?

Comment: Also teamsite will be an SPWeb object, not SPSite.

Comment: @AndreasScharf `teamsite.Url` property does not exist in Managed Client Object model. I haven't been able to find the property/method that would serve my purpose.

Comment: @JamesLove Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I've updated my question.

Comment: I assume you are refering to the script client object model. Please leave a comment if you needed guidance for the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" one ^_^

Comment: To get list Properties like URL, ID , Title . Please see below link. http://yeshagrawal.blogspot.in/2013/09/sharepoint-2013-get-sp-list-title-id.html

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: FYI - They added the Url property to the web object (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web) in SharePoint 2013  https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.url.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79732)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use the available property to build the url you require. Just be aware that many of the property must be accessed with a *get_method* sintax.

For the SP.Site use [the get_url() "property"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550732.aspx).
For the SP.Web use [the get_serverRelativeUrl() property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550064.aspx) and build up the full url.

For the list... don't know if there is an easier way, but you can resort to the [get_serverRelativeUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee547617.aspx) property of the root folder ([SP.List.get_rootFolder();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee551348.aspx)). Then build the full url from there.

EDIT:
As a reference for those that are using the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" namespace.
On the Site object you can use [the .Url property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.url.aspx). Since the Web object does not provide an Url property use [the ServerRelativeUrl one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.serverrelativeurl.aspx) and build the full url as needed.
Also, you must still compensate for the List object not providing any url property. As above, you can resort using the [ServerRelativeUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.serverrelativeurl.aspx) of the [RootFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.rootfolder.aspx) of the list.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` model, but the method names are virtually the same and you resolved my question. Thanks.

Comment: ops, sorry. I had read SPSite as SP.Site, so I automatically switched to javascript thinking mode ^_^''. I will update the answer when I get some time on hand.

Answer (score 2):

This is how SP.Web absolute url can be constructed:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var site = clientContext.get_site();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
clientContext.load(site,'ServerRelativeUrl', 'Url');
clientContext.load(web, 'ServerRelativeUrl');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
    var fullWebUrl = site.get_url().replace(site.get_serverRelativeUrl(), 
web.get_serverRelativeUrl());
alert(fullWebUrl);
}), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {  }));
```

Comment: This helped me, but it only works when site.get_serverRelativeUrl() is longer than "/". A more flexible solution is:         
if (site.get_serverRelativeUrl() == "/")
            return site.get_url() + web.get_serverRelativeUrl();
        else
            return site.get_url().replace(site.get_serverRelativeUrl(), web.get_serverRelativeUrl());