# How to get the "full URL" of a List in SharePoint JSOM

Tags: jsom, splistitem

```
function getListsInformation()
{
    debugger;
    var oClientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWebsite = oClientContext.get_web();
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('Students');
    oClientContext.load(oList);
    oClientContext.executeQueryAsync(ListInformationSuccess,ListInformationFailed);   
}

function ListInformationSuccess()
{
    var listTitle = oList.get_title();
    var listUrl = oList.get_url();
    alert("List Title = " + listTitle + "\n List URL = "+listUrl);
}
```

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23517/getting-the-urls-of-the-sharepoint-sites-lists-and-list-views-using-managed-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While loading the list object make sure you include the properties to get url. Also List object in JSOM doesn't have method `get_url()` like Site or Web object have in JSOM. In order to retrieve the complete List URL, I use list default view url property along with `window.location.origin` property.

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");
ctx.load(list, 'DefaultViewUrl');

ctx.executeQueryAsync(done, fail);

function done(){
    var listFullUrl = window.location.origin + list.get_defaultViewUrl();
    console.log(listFullUrl);
}

function fail(){
    console.log("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getListsInformation()
{
    var oClientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWebsite = oClientContext.get_web();
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('Students');
    oClientContext.load(oWebsite);
    oClientContext.load(oList,'Id','Title','DefaultViewUrl','ParentWebUrl');
    oClientContext.executeQueryAsync(ListInformationSuccess,ListInformationFailed);   
}
function ListInformationSuccess()
{
    var webUrl = oWebsite.get_url();
    var parentUrl = oList.get_parentWebUrl();
    var listfullurl = webUrl.substr(0,webUrl.length-parentUrl.length).concat(oList.get_defaultViewUrl());
    alert(listfullurl);

}
```